# Best method to connect to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

Am I using a bad method to conntect to my mysql db?
Im currently using:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("mysql_table", $con);
```

Comment: Signs point to yes, that API is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You should switch to using mysqli or PDO - mysql_ functions have been soft deprecated and will eventually be removed. mysqli_ and PDO allow you to use prepared statements, eliminating the risk of SQL injection. You can find more about these extensions in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

Use ADODB library. The code to connect would look like:

```
$db = ADONewConnection('mysqlt');
$db->Connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can do prepared statements easily:

```
// $sql is your sql statement
// $sqlArray is an array of user entered variables
$query = $db->execute($sql, $sqlArray);
```

It's easy to get the data:

```
$row = $query->FetchRow();
```

Comment: What did I just read ?

Comment: Yes I have, and I have also heard of ADODB.  It's nice to have many tools in the tool belt.

Comment: Like I said, I've upvoted because I like alternatives. But I'm not sure that the adodb driver is not limited in it's functionality. Do you know more?

Comment: @hek2mgl I use it in a few projects.  I don't know much about it under the hood.  I find it easy to use, and it supports prepared statements - the two things I was looking for.